# Cargo Collective and Tooltipster

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I've tried to look all over for some kind of guidance but I'm really not sure what to do. I've come to this site a lot for previously answered questions but couldn't find anything concerning cargo and tooltipster. It might not even be possible, I'm not sure.

---

**QUESTION**: I have followed tooltipsters steps the best I possibly can. (http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#getting-started) I feel like I've done everything right, I'm not sure why it's not working. Please bear in mind that I'm extremely new to jquery and I'm trying to do my best, haha.

This is my site: http://emengel.net/ I'm not sure what other information to provide. I know cargo already runs on jquery, am I able to have tooltipster too?

Comment: Please construct a jsFiddle demo.  But including a demo link does not excuse having no code in your post.  It's important to also show your code in case the links go dead.